# What to call it when someone who refuses to eat when offered food, but not because he doesn't want to eat, but because he's being polite

Tags: word-choice

This is a word in Mongolian: нэрэлх

So you'd use the word like "Ид ид, битгий нэрэлх", essentially meaning, "Please eat, don't be shy to eat".

Shy to eat seems a bit weird, can anyone recommend a similar word or concept in English?

Comment: When I pasted your word into Google and asked for a translation from Mongolian I was given the English translation 'distill'. Does that make sense ?

Comment: No, that's another unrelated term that has the same spelling. It just means to distill stuff chemically.

Comment: If I interpreted your question correctly, there is a Chinese word for this too.  The closest English words I can think of are **civility**, **ceremony** *(stand on ceremony)*, **etiquette**.

Comment: @Jalene What is the Chinese word?

Comment: @chintogtokh 客气 Kèqì。the person is being 客气 for not tucking in. The host will say 不要客气 which is almost similar to *don't stand on ceremony*. However, the word *ceremony* makes it sound rather elaborated and formal.

Answer (score 3):

Since being polite in the West would mean that you should accept whatever food you're offered, the exact opposite happens and people end up eating a meal that they don't like out of politeness! Hence, I don't think there's an exact equivalent for this in English.

The closest word I can think of is ***[coy](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coy)*** (adj. someone who pretends not to want something).

There's also the literary term ***[accismus](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-accismus-rhetoric-1689055)***, which is a form of irony in which a person feigns a lack of interest in something that he or she actually desires.

Answer (score 2):

One finds usages such as this from [Shimmer](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1T5RAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA25), by B.J. Robertson, page 25:

> Now you eat. I do not stand on formality.

Or this from [Faith](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YjyaItMrBtIC&pg=PA97), by Donald Eaton, page 97:

> Eat up. We do not stand on formality here.

As Jalene commented above, 'stand on ceremony' is also possible (e.g. in [Just Maagy](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5e29BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA19) by Virginia Stringer, page 19.)

> The girl is hungry and we have breakfast ready. Let's not stand on
>   ceremony. Come in! Let's eat!

Also it's not wrong to use the word 'shy' in this situation. For example, here's an indirect use from the novel [The Cheetah Chase](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qhndHCFv1swC) by Karin McQuillan (1995), page 127:

> The princess picked out a date with her long red-enamelled fingernails
>   and popped it into her mouth. "Please, eat." I was famished and didn't
>   need a further invitation. Wynn wasn't *shy*, either.

In Indian English, it's fairly common to say something like "There is no formality, please eat."

Answer (score 0):

You’ve actually got the basics, but the wording is a bit off...

Eat up, don’t be shy!